Scaling istack and setIntervalRestrictions produces negative numbers
The scaling of istack and setIntervalRestrictions will result in negative values for istack 1, and it will break free from the setIntervalRestrictions restriction. istack 1 will experience axis data flipping.
Dragging and zooming with the mouse will cause this issue.
chart.yAxis.dispose();
let axisX = chart
  .getDefaultAxisX()
  .setInterval({
    start: 0,
    end: 10,
  })
  .setIntervalRestrictions({
    startMin: 0,
    endMax: 10,
  });

let axisYOne = chart
  .addAxisY({ iStack: 1 })
  .setInterval({
    start: 0,
    end: 10,
  })
  .setLength({
    pixels: 200,
  })
  .setIntervalRestrictions({
    startMin: 0,
    endMax: 10,
  });
let axisYTwo = chart
  .addAxisY({ iStack: 3 })
  .setInterval({
    start: 0,
    end: 10,
  })
  .setLength({
    pixels: 200,
  })
  .setIntervalRestrictions({
    startMin: 0,
    endMax: 10,
  });
chart
  .addLineSeries({
    yAxis: axisYOne,
  })
  .addArraysXY([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
chart
  .addLineSeries({
    yAxis: axisYTwo,
  })
  .addArraysXY([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);


